# Check if each div has an element with a specific class inside it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

I have a tree of `div` elements with the same `class` but different `id` as we can see below:

```
<div class="resultsAnalitics" id="result_0">
  <span class="successResults">Success</span>
</div>

<div class="resultsAnalitics" id="result_1">
  <span class="warningResults">Warning</span>
</div>

<div class="resultsAnalitics" id="result_2">
  <span class="dangerResults">Danger</span>
</div>
```

I have to check which class exists in each of these divs and show on the console. For this I created the following code:

```
$( ".resultsAnalitics" ).each(function( index ) {
var current = $(this).attr('id');

console.log("I'm on div: " + current);

if($(this).has('.successResults')){
console.log('The results is success');
}

if($(this).has('.warningResults')){
console.log('The results is warning');
}

if($(this).has('.dangerResults')){
console.log('The results is danger');
}


});
```

I expected to get the following results like this:

> I'm on div: result_0 The results is success
>
> I'm on div: result_1 The results is warning
>
> I'm on div: result_2 The results is danger

But I'm getting the following results:

> I'm on div: result_0 The results is success The results is warning The
>   results is danger
>
> I'm on div: result_1 The results is success The results is warning The
>   results is danger
>
> I'm on div: result_2 The results is success The results is warning The
>   results is danger

How I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One efficiency solution is to use `.children` method, because you have to check if `span` children of `each` div has one certain `class`.

> `children` method gets the children of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

```js
$( ".resultsAnalitics" ).each(function( ) {
var current = $(this).attr('id');

console.log("I'm on div: " + current);

if($(this).children('.successResults').length){
console.log('The results is success');
}

if($(this).children('.warningResults').length){
console.log('The results is warning');
}

if($(this).children('.dangerResults').length){
console.log('The results is danger');
}


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="resultsAnalitics" id="result_0">
<span class="successResults">Success</span>
</div>

<div class="resultsAnalitics" id="result_1">
<span class="warningResults">Warning</span>
</div>

<div class="resultsAnalitics" id="result_2">
<span class="dangerResults">Danger</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You were close.

The problem is that the [`.has()` method](https://api.jquery.com/has/) will still return a [jQuery object](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/) even if an element isn't selected. As the relevant [jQuery documentation states](https://api.jquery.com/has/), the `.has()` method will "reduce the set of matched elements to those that have a descendant that matches the selector or DOM element".

This means that your conditional statements were always true, which is why the message was logged regardless of whether any elements were found.

To check if any elements are returned from the jQuery object, check the `.length` property of the jQuery object in your conditional statements. In doing so, the value will be `0` when an element isn't found.

Your updated code would be:

```
$(".resultsAnalitics").each(function(index) {
  console.log("I'm on div: " + this.id);

  if ($(this).has('.successResults').length) {
    console.log('The results is success');
  }

  if ($(this).has('.warningResults').length) {
    console.log('The results is warning');
  }

  if ($(this).has('.dangerResults').length) {
    console.log('The results is danger');
  }
});
```

Comment: Very well explained! `.has()` is not the problem, although the keyword `has` may sound like it should return a `boolean`

Comment: @PeterKA - Yeah, I definitely agree that it should return a boolean, especially since it isn't consistent with other methods, such as [the `.is()` method](http://api.jquery.com/is/), which returns a boolean as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You could go the other way and target each of the classes specifically and then find the id of the parent container. Notethat I added another success div at the bottom to demonstrate that all success divs give the parent ID and then the warning and then the danger.

```js
$(".successResults" ).each(function(){
var parent = $(this).parent().attr('id');
  console.log("I'm on div: " + parent + ' - The results is success');
});

$(".warningResults" ).each(function(){
var parent = $(this).parent().attr('id');
  console.log("I'm on div: " + parent + ' - The results is warning');
});

$(".dangerResults" ).each(function(){
var parent = $(this).parent().attr('id');
  console.log("I'm on div: " + parent + ' - The results is danger');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="resultsAnalitics" id="result_0">
<span class="successResults">Success</span>
</div>

<div class="resultsAnalitics" id="result_1">
<span class="warningResults">Warning</span>
</div>

<div class="resultsAnalitics" id="result_2">
<span class="dangerResults">Danger</span>
</div>

<div class="resultsAnalitics" id="result_3">
<span class="successResults">Success</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.find()` (checking length of search result) and use loop to make it more elegant and elastic for further changes.

http://codepen.io/themeler/pen/mRgKLP

```
$( ".resultsAnalitics" ).each(function( index ) {
    var $this = $(this),
        current = $this.attr('id'),
        states = [
            {
                name: '.successResults',
                msg: 'The results is success'
            },
            {
                name: '.warningResults',
                msg: 'The results is warning'
            },
            {
                name: '.dangerResults',
                msg: 'The results is danger'
            }
        ];

    for (var i = 0; i < states.length; i++) {
        if ($this.find(states[i].name).length) console.log("I'm on div: " + current, states[i].msg)
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Grabs all classes that end with Results within resultsAnalitics     
var results = $(".resultsAnalitics span[class$='Results']");

// loop through each, grabbing parent id and innerHTML
results.each(function(idx, node) {
    console.log("I'm on div:", node.parentNode.id, "- Result are:", node.innerHTML);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use jQuery "find" method to check out for specific elements in a particular element.It returns jQuery object. Using this object we can further check for number of elements by using 'length'.

```
<div class="resultsAnalitics" id="result_0">
  <span class="successResults">Success</span>
</div>

<div class="resultsAnalitics" id="result_1">
  <span class="warningResults">Warning</span>
</div>

<div class="resultsAnalitics" id="result_2">
  <span class="dangerResults">Danger</span>
</div>

<script>
$( ".resultsAnalitics" ).each(function( index ) {
var current = $(this).attr('id');

console.log("I'm on div: " + current);

if($(this).find('.successResults').length){
console.log('The results is success');
}

if($(this).find('.warningResults').length){
console.log('The results is warning');
}

if($(this).find('.dangerResults').length){
console.log('The results is danger');
}


});
</script>
```